# postMessage between two websites

Tags: javascript

I've got two websites aaa.com and bbb.com. I want to, on button click, postMessage from website aaa.com to website bbb.com but cannot get it done.

I'm calling from aaa.com:

`window.postMessage('this is test', 'bbb.com');`

and listening on bbb.com:

`window.addEventListener('message', function(e) { alert(e.data); }, false);`

Please point me where I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

;) oh, man , this way it won't work at all, at least to my understanding

maybee this could help you:

- read about javascirpt and cross-domain-calls
- read about curl
- read about $_GET $_POST / $_SERVER - Variables (f.e for php)
- try making simple form in php to understand webserver - mechanics

basically if you want to send something to a site, the target-site should have a form (post) / url ( get ) where it accepts this. so you send a HTTP-REQUEST where your parameters/message is UrlEncoded.

i like the basic idea of what you trying to achieve, since this is not "so unrealistic" in application programming .... but the thing which is bothering you i think is the "stateless" http-protocl , and the fact that javascirpt is ClientSide-ONLY ;)

you possibly could build a javascript runnin on the client listening for connection... but thats also out of my scope --- maybee someone else knows ...

hope it helps 
cu

Comment: I think the new html5 feature he is using is made to precisely adress this issue

Comment: so ? that sounds like a joke , but if true , pleas provide a link to the featrue which you think does this... possibilty is great that i missed that ....

Comment: oh my god ;) that really looks as if it would do that - so i gotta stick to reading - thx meanwhile - looking forward to use this altough im sceptic but lets see

Comment: no problem
it was also sounding too scary for me to believe it :D